# show the div even after the page reload

Tags: javascript, html

On click of a button, I am showing a div by using

```
document.getElementById('message-box').style.display="block";
```

but when the page is reloaded this div disappears again. I want the div to stay until i explicitly close it with `x` button. How I can do this?

Comment: Set and check cookie. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Comment: any example? never mind, I am just a newbie in js

Comment: As @nevermind said you need to have a variable in cookie or localStorage. Set the cookie or variable to true when the button to show div is clicked. And set to false once the x is clicked. Combine that with Vassiliy's answer at bottom to show div after reload if the value of cookie or variable is true.

You can find many tutorials and examples on handling cookies and localStorage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This simple example will do what you want to achieve

html:

```
<div class='hidden' id='hiddenDiv'>NOT SHOWN UNTIL YOU CLICK IT!! <span>
        <input type='button' value='X' onclick='closeClick()'>
    </span>

</div>
<input type='button' value='show me the div' onclick='openClick()' />
```

JS:

```
function openClick() {
    document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').style.display = "block";
    sessionStorage.setItem('clicked', true);
}

function closeClick() {
    document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').style.display = "none";
    sessionStorage.removeItem('clicked');
}

window.onload = function () {
    var data = sessionStorage.getItem('clicked');
    if (data == 'true') {
        openClick();
    }
};
```

[fiddle example](https://fiddle.jshell.net/0an7wmke/4/)

Comment: your example works on fiddle but not on my laravel application. strange :/

Comment: this is my html
`<span date-userid="{{$user->id}}" style="color: #000; text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; " onclick="openMessageBox(this)" class="user" class="inner-list-item">{{$user->name}}</span>`
<br>JS<br>
`function openMessageBox(elem){
document.getElementById('message-box').style.display="block";
    sessionStorage.setItem('clicked', true);
}`
My function recieves an argument too, may be this is the problem?

Comment: session values are being set and unset but the div does not show up after page reload.

Comment: did you add the 'window.onload' function? You won't be able to use 'this' in the onload function of course, also mind that the 'getSession' will return a string, and not a boolean.

Comment: yes I added the `window.onload` function but as I said my function receives an argument(current reference to the object) so we have to pass the argument to call the function. This is the problem.

Comment: your solution is correct, I have figured out the problem with my function.

Answer (score 2):

I am not going to write code on here, since it makes a developer lazy by copy/pasting, but i am going to tell you how you can solve it.

The issue in here is that, you refresh the page, and the state of that div is removed, since is not a persistent state.

A solution for this, is either cookies, or localStorage, where you can set off a variable, if the button is off or not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok I got it that I have to store the cookie(a bool variable) for this. But when the page reloads and I get the cookie value, now how i would show the same div again?

Comment: Hey,

I suppose you have to check on page load either with JavaScript document.onload = function () {}, or with jQuery .ready().

When you make sure the condition is correct, you apply that style.

Comment: Better use localStorage, i would think twice before pulling my hands on cookies

Comment: That depends on what is the browser support the OP needs to handle, if its  some prehistoric browser, then i would go with cookies. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
window.onload = function() {document.getElementById('message-box').style.display="block";};
```

Comment: this will happen even before the click, I think he wants it to happen only after click

Comment: The div should only show after button click. But should remain open even after reload unless closed.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. The best way is cookie as nevermind wrote in comment.